# How can i get all the posts from my group page and delete them all togeather getting error?

Tags: c#, facebook

I have access token i can post to my group page.
Now i want to get the posts and delete them all.

```
var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                var query = string.Format(@"{{
""posts"":""SELECT post_id, actor_id, attachment, permalink, app_data, type, likes.count,comments.count,message,source_id ,updated_time,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = {0} and updated_time > {1} and type > 0 LIMIT 100"",
""photo_posts"":""SELECT photo_id, src, width, height FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.fbid FROM #posts where type=247) and width > 300 and width < 500 order by width desc""}}", 1378943962355167);

                dynamic parameters1 = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters1.q = query;

                IList<dynamic> postsRaw = ObjectExtensions.ToData(objFacebookClient.Get("fql", parameters1
```

The problem for now im not sure if this part of code is good or not but now ObjectExtensions is not exist on the line:

```
IList<dynamic> postsRaw = ObjectExtensions.ToData(objFacebookClient.Get("fql", parameters1
```

Cant figure out what to do .

Comment: Edited my question now to make it more clear what i need.

Comment: why do you use a different account?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(AccessPageToken);
                objFacebookClient.Delete("344087212396598_344775698994416").ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Thanks.